# Pointer to NULL

Tags: assembly

I have this function:

```
int execve(const char* filename, char* const argv[], char* const envp[]);
```

And I need set to NULL the envp parameter, so I need a pointer to NULL in the edx register before execute the function (better said, the syscall with int 0x80). The question is, can I do:

```
mov eax, 0
mov edx, eax  ; edx points to NULL, no to some address that contains NULL
```

or need I do:

```
push 0
mov edx, esp ; edx points to some address that contains NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the operation system. In Linux you can use directly a NULL pointer.

[man execve](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html):

> On Linux, argv and envp can be specified as NULL.  In both cases, this
>   has the same effect as specifying the argument as a pointer to a list
>   containing a single null pointer.  Do not take advantage of this
>   misfeature!  It is nonstandard and nonportable: on most other UNIX
>   systems doing this will result in an error (EFAULT).