# pathname vs arguments for execve parameters

Tags: c, execve

I am trying to implement a simple shell program that runs user input commands. I want the user to enter "ls" or "dir" and have the shell run /bin/ls or /bin/dir . For the execve argument what would be correct:

```
char *args[] ={"/bin/", "ls", NULL};
//Fork, pid, etc...then
execve(args[0], args+1, NULL);
```

Or would it be something different?? I've see some people using `/bin/ls` as the pathname and then no arguments or `ls` as the pathname and `\bin` for the environment? I tried what I had above and it didn't work so I want to know if it is the arguments I am sending it or whether I should be looking elsewhere in my code for the problem. Note I am not interested in other variations of execve such as execvp. I am on a Linux system. Thanks

Comment: [This answer may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507950/calling-ls-with-execv/28508441#28508441). Note that it's about `execv`, but the only difference between `execv` and `execve` is that `execve` takes a third argument. Pretty sure that you aren't supposed to set that third argument to NULL. If you don't need the third argument, then you should be using `execv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PATHNAME

The pathname in `execve()` must be the *full* path to the executable, such as `/bin/ls`. If using `execvpe()`, you could use `ls` alone as the pathname, but as you already specified, you don’t want to use that.

## ARGUMENTS

The arguments should be an array of strings, one for each space-separated argument specified on the command line. The last one should be NULL. The first argument should be the pathname itself. For example:

```
char* args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-la", "foo/bar", NULL};
```

## ENVIRONMENT

The environment variables cannot be omitted when using `execve()`. In **some implementations**, `NULL` can be passed as the last argument to `execve()`, but this is [not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28210123/15272584). Instead, you should pass a pointer to a null pointer; essentially an empty array of environment variables.

## Putting it together

```
char *args[] ={"/bin/ls", "-foo", "bar", NULL};
//Fork, pid, etc...then
char* nullstr = NULL;
execve(args[0], args, &nullstr);
```

Comment: This works with the change `execve(args[0], args, NULL)` -- the nullstr threw an error. Thank you very much!

Comment: Very strange… what was the error?

Answer (score 1):

From [execve](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) *[emphasis added]*:

> ```
>    int execve(const char *pathname, char *const argv[],
>              char *const envp[]);
> ```

> **execve() executes the program referred to by pathname.**  This
> causes the program that is currently being run by the calling
> process to be replaced with a new program, with newly initialized
> stack, heap, and (initialized and uninitialized) data segments.

> pathname must be either a binary executable, or a script starting
> with a line of the form:

```
   #!interpreter [optional-arg]
```

> For details of the latter case, see "Interpreter scripts" below.

> **argv is an array of pointers to strings passed to the new program
> as its command-line arguments. By convention, the first of these
> strings (i.e., argv[0]) should contain the filename associated
> with the file being executed.**  The argv array must be terminated
> by a NULL pointer.  (Thus, in the new program, argv[argc] will be
> NULL.)

In your case, the `pathname` should be `"/bin/ls"` and not `"/bin/"`. If you want to pass any command line argument with the command, you can provide first argument them with `argv` vector index `1`, second argument with index `2` and so on and terminate the argument vector with `NULL`.

A sample program which replace the current executable image with `/bin/ls` program and runs `/bin/ls testfile`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {
    char *args[] = {"/bin/ls", "testfile", NULL};
    // here you can call fork and then call execve in child process
    execve(args[0], args, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out 
testfile
```